# Adding an App Token to a URLSession with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, urlsession

I am making a request to a public API endpoint and they recommend using a given app token. I have the token, but I can't seem to find a way to pass it into the URLSession.

I included the relevant code for the URLSession below. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
func fetchTotalsData(completionHandler: @escaping([Totals]) -> Void){

    let url = URL(string: "https://data.ct.gov/resource/rf3k-f8fg.json")!
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        
        guard let data = data else { return }
        
        do {
            let totalsData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Totals].self, from: data)
            completionHandler(totalsData)
        }
        catch {
            let error = error
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Usually token should be inside headers. You can set headers while you create a request. So you have to use more advanced code than shown in your question. So either dig into URLSession or use some libs like CodyFire, Alamofire, etc.

Comment: I fully support imike's comment. However, I would like to suggest to _first_ try out the pure URLSession approach with configuring the URLRequest (or alternatively the URLSession, see docs). Then dive a bit into the HTTP protocol reading about requests and responses and how they work. ;)